# Batch rename files in Adobe Bridge

Tags: regex, adobe, rename, bridge

I want to Batch Rename a few thousand files. I have one part of the regular expression figured out just not the first part.

The filename is the employeeID_employeeName-sequence number. I would like to only keep the employeeID_employee name.

For example the file 123456_John Smith-00001.pdf should become 123456_John Smith.pdf

I was able to use Batch Rename, then string substitution then, find [-\d?] but that only changes the filename to _John Smith.pdf

[Please see batch rename example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OggTH.png)

Comment: You probably want `-\d+(\.\w+)$` and replace with `$1`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on the adobe syntax, but here is how I would normally do it in regex - https://regex101.com/r/GaSlId/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression that worked was by Wiktor Stribiżew in the comment above. In the string substitution field I placed -\d+(.\w+)$ and left the replace with field empty.